# It will be better if Navigationbar on Stackoverflow will be sticky

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, top-bar

When we are moving down a page, we can not notice, if there is any notification, if the navigation at the top will be sticky , It will be really helpful. Is there any possibilities, we can see this in near future or , is there any other way to get notified.

The question [Position fixed navigation bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273024/position-fixed-navigation-bar) has an answer suggesting using a script, but is it secure to use these type of scripts ??

Is there any possibilities stackoverflow can make the notification to be like gmail desktop notification ?

Comment: @psubsee2003 you are correct, I gone through that , and it is the same question, but there is no good solution to it, someone has used some script to do so, is it the correct way ?

Comment: No, sticky top menus suck. The Home key on your keyboard has a function.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you put a more descriptive answer, please. I think your view on this will add more idea on this to me.

Comment: I can't, your question has been closed as a duplicate. I also don't know what more I can explain. I don't like fixed menus on web sites, and you can press the `Home` key on your keyboard to move to the top of the page.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have edited my question, to explain what is my original idea behind the question, I want to be notified for comments, answer when I am reading answers or discussion down the page.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have edited my question with the inputs, I got from that post and discussion here.

Comment: Try searching. First Google hit for "stack overflow desktop notifications": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47750/stack-overflow-desktop-notifier

Comment: @CodeCaster what I should do with this question now, I should delete it or  flag it . thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Feel free to let it be. It's a duplicate, so it'll help people who search for the answer using terms used in your post.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok.

Comment: @CodeCaster what you think about sticky navbar today ?

Comment: Disabled and leaving it that way. However high my screen is, I don't like 60 pixels (three lines of text) being stolen all the time by a bar I hardly ever use.

Comment: @CodeCaster Do you think a notification (not exactly popup) appearing to notify would have been a better solution ? like skype web or gmail but I do not think the popup is the better idea, something else in place of poup . thank you for you response  :) .

Comment: No, because when I'm done with reading or writing a question or answer, I return to the homepage, /questions or my profile, where the bar will be visible again. I see the top bar often enough to not need it permanently visible, nor do I need to be notified _immediately_ of inbox messages.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sometimes long answer and question may take more time than you want others to wait for in those moments, it is helpful to get notified . But it is personal preference .

Answer (score 5):

Most of our users prefer to *not* have the topbar fixed.

As posted in the linked duplicate, you can use a user script - that will only affect you.

Comment: Is there a possibility we can be notified instantly in stackoverflow, like desktop notification on gmail or the sticky navbar to be optional for user on setting or somewhere else ?

Comment: and Finally we are with sticky navigation :D

Comment: With the option to turn it off.

Comment: Any way, it is helpful to know if someone has answered your question or queried something about your question or OP has asked a question on your answer when you are busy in reading other useful posts .

Comment: Unfortunately, it happened anyway.