# We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation

Tags: discussion, top-bar

As part of our work on updating site navigation we have recently asked y'all to [help us test the new top nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week) and provide bug reports and other feedback.

One feature that has garnered a lot of strong feelings from a number of people in the community was the fixed navigation - some people truly [dislike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar) it, though a number of other people have also told us how much they do like it (we have had multiple [requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273024/position-fixed-navigation-bar) [over](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312682/it-will-be-better-if-navigationbar-on-stackoverflow-will-be-sticky) the [years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342058/keep-stack-overflow-topbar-fixed-at-top-of-page) to make the old top bar fixed).

This has been a somewhat controversial feature from the moment it was proposed - internally and externally, though in all the user testing we have done (focus groups and interviews), not a single person raised it as an issue.

Given this is very much something of personal choice and that many people feel strongly about, we have gone ahead with adding a user preference to control the fixed navigation behaviour.

You can access this option via [your preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#fixedHeader), where you will be greeted with this option:

> [image: unpin navigation preference]

This works as you'd expect - check the checkbox to disable the fixed header, uncheck it to enable it. This will take immediate effect on the current page, though if you have the site open in other tabs, you will need to refresh them.

The option is per-site, so you will need to disable/enable it on each site that has the new navigation (Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Meta at this point) - which is exactly the same way the keyboard shortcuts work.

We are taking on a bit of debt by maintaining two versions of something that exists everywhere, but we felt the objection from our more experienced users to seeing it all of the time was valid, and important to address. Settings to add frolicking unicorns or rainbow backgrounds are probably a bit too expensive for us to consider.

Comment: This will also work with the new, new nav right?

Comment: _"focus groups and interviews"_ How are these selected? Am I right in assuming _"Sticky enabled"_ is the default setting?

Comment:  Woot woot! 

Comment: @Cerbrus - yes, sticky is default.

Comment: So, [who's in charge of maintaining that…?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343132#comment444448_343132) :)

Comment: All of us, @deceze, all of us (devs and designers)

Comment: [よろしくお願いします](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37182/88) 

Comment: Expression of good will to you and the whole community too, @deceze

Comment: Well, I shouldn't look a gift horse in the mouth (thank you so much for listening!), but I wonder why this is per-site? Surely the preference is logically a global one. Is it just technically easier to implement per-site?

Comment: @CodyGray - infrastructure, unfortunately. We would like to make keyboard-shortcuts global as well, but are not setup for that. One day...

Comment: Once the dust settles, I'd be curious to know how many people will choose a setting different from the default one.

Comment: If I could vote this up several times, I would! Thanks for listening to us.

Comment: Perfect!! Just what I wanted. Any ETA when this will be available on other sites except SO/MSO?

Comment: weird... I disabled the sticky nav earlier today, but a few minutes ago it reverted to sticky again. just re-disabled.

Comment: @KevinB - did you possibly do it on SO but not MSO? These are considered separate sites, as far as the preferences are concerned.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - no ETA yet. We plan to launch on SO/MSO next week, localized SO sites (and their metas) after that. As far as I know, we don't have a complete plan yet for the rest of the network.

Comment: That is possible, I don't recall.

Comment: @Oded thanks, what about MSE? :)

Comment: Same bucket as "rest of network", @Sha

Comment: Now... can we talk about a setting for the color? Or just changing it for everyone?

Comment: Great, but **can we make the Meta settings echo the main site settings**?  Like KevinB, I immediately disabled this annoyance -- only to think there was a bug with Meta.

Comment: Huzzah! That is all.

Comment: To nitpick very minor details, is there a specific reason to have this set up a "check to disable", instead of "check to enable" (with checked being the default)? It's not that confusing, but it still feels weird…

Comment: Why is there no option to toggle this for all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @JackManey - because it (the new header) was only launched for Stack Overflow (and its meta). We will be rolling out other changes slowly across the network.

Comment: It would be nice if the setting lasted longer than five fucking minutes before somehow reverting. I've had to "Disable fixed site navigation" twice now on Meta.

Comment: @JackManey - you sure you didn't have to do it once on meta and once on SO? We are looking at ways to make it a global setting.

Comment: Thus far, I've toggled the setting on *twice* on meta and once on SO. It seems to be working for now.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR MAKING THIS AN OPTION. Finally, some relative sanity around here. Sweet top bar btw, I finally got it.

Comment: @Oded looks like the reverting was a fluke (maybe a caching issue on my end?). The navbars are now consistently non-sticky on both meta and SO.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @JackManey :)

Comment: @JackManey Fwiw, I did notice after changing the option that I had to do a shift+reload (full reload) to apply it. In particular navigating back out of the settings page with the back button in Chrome, you won't see the change applied. So yeah, caching, I guess.

Comment: The new nav is awesome. Not seeing any reason to complain now that the sticky bit can be switched. Great work!

Comment: It is against my company's policy to log into any form of communities using our workstations. How can I disable the sticky bar without connecting to my account?

Comment: @Hay - a user stylesheet.

Comment: @Oded Can't install Chrome extensions on my workstation. Being a bank, everything is locked down.

Comment: @Hay - guess you are out of luck and will have to get used to the sticky bar.

Comment: Thank you!  Credit where it's due: yours is the first "sticky" feature I've seen that didn't completely break typical Web browsing (meaning `PgDn` or `spacebar`) by hiding the content.  I still turned it off the instant I read this, but I found it merely awkward and frustrating, as opposed to awful and infuriating.  (It goes without saying that the "descending curtain of doom" style nav bar that crawls out from under the browser interface to devour whatever you were trying to read is Pure Evil, and I'm grateful that it never appeared here.)

Comment: @BrockAdams this is hilarious meta site also people!  Come on

Comment: Can you please also add an option "Use small icons on navbar" to reduce the height of the thing?

Comment: Ah yes, one should also consider to cut down the logo on the left to a no-text/small-width-version as the window size gets smaller.

Comment: it's just too wide. make it a bit narrower - a setting, perhaps? - and more people will love it. it *is* nice to see rep or messages notifications instantly w/out having to scroll away to the top. also, I prefer it when my browser is in full screen mode.

Comment: @WillNess - it is the exact width of the content.

Comment: @Oded http://imgur.com/a/2X0jU lots of empty space there. search box and logo are the only two really wide things, and that's not necessary. both could just be the same width as the identicon. Fonts could be tweaked, etc. (also, I'm on 125% zoom most of the time).

Comment: @Oded basically, just *one* additional setting  - *scaling factor for the task bar* - would fix all that.

Comment: @WillNess - I've seen at least 5 requests for different "one more setting" by now. We cannot and will not accommodate them all. One preference - make the header sticky or not - no more.

Comment: @Oded It was just a suggestion, not a demand, no need to get so defensive. Don't want to make improvements, fine by me. The giant task bar won't do.

Comment: When will be the "Disable top bar stickiness" option added in other Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 67):

Oh not a *setting*.
Now I have *yet another thing* to choose!

Seriously though, thanks! No *"if, but, why"*, just Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation... oh, wait

Comment: Hear hear. I was getting used to the bar being stickied, but having it unstickied... I can't fully explain it but it brings more peace, the eyes don't automatically shoot up to the top-right corner constantly. So good to have this configurable.

Comment: I still don't know how I feel about the sticky part, but my therapist is helping me work through it.

Comment: @Tim Post: How long until someone flags your comment as rude or offensive for trivializing mental health issues? ;)

Answer (score 35):

Can this ***please*** be a global setting so I don't have to check the box on every single one of the dozen-odd SE sites I browse?

Comment: [See here:](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update/343815#comment447978_343780) _"I need to talk so some people - but I plan to make that setting propagate across the network. ..."_ From NickCraver, a dev. (In other words, looks like this is the plan.)

Answer (score 22):

This is good; I like it, thank you.

I find the terminology confusing, though. I realise that from an implementation perspective, "fixed" is the correct term for the sticky mode. But from a user perspective, I tend to think of "fixed" as meaning "fixed to the top of the page" rather than "fixed to the top of the window".

Perhaps we could rename this setting, or add some explanatory text alongside the checkbox that *really* explains what the setting does?

Comment: Agreed, *"Disable fixed site navigation"* is pretty confusing in more ways than one. Something along the lines of *"Use sticky header"* with an explainer of *"When checked, the top navigation header will always be visible at the top of the screen"* would be much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - we have changed the phrasing (with you in the next build)

Comment: @Oded: Ta duck :)

Comment: I don't want to make the creation of a succinct description of the navbar even more challenging, but: I'll note that the new navbar *is* fixed to the top of each and every page when the web page is printed.

Answer (score 12):

Spelling error: "stickyness" should be "stickiness".

Joke for 5-year-olds:
**Q:** What's brown and sticky?
**A:**

> A stick.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Seems I can't spel. Fixed in the next buyld.

Comment: My (late) brother's favorite joke.

Answer (score -2):

Please reconsider the default option for this. I get that some people want one way and some want another, so an option is great, but whenever you have an configurable option for something, you still have to consciously choose a default.

I suspect most people would prefer non-sticky (my only data, the OP has one link requesting unsticky with +122 points and three links requesting sticky with each around -8 points). I also suspect that about 99% of users won't know there is an option (or even that there are options at all).

I understand from the [blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation) that you guys are really interested in engagements and A/B tests and other nonsense, but please don't try to make this site more like Quora. Quora already exists for the people who like that sort of thing.

Comment: considering the target of this change is putting those links in a place where the majority of users (users who get here from google) will see them and potentially click them (intentionally or otherwise,) defaulting to sticky would be the most likely option to benefit the purpose of this change.

Comment: Maybe after time they can count how many users disable it and change defaults accordingly but really, as long as it's an option, who cares what the default is. It's easy enough to click the checkbox. Btw, floating nav bars don't make Quora Quora, Quora makes Quora Quora.

Comment: My point is that optimizing for click thrus instead of user experience is very Quora.

Comment: ["In the past year, we fully integrated our by-developers, for-developers Jobs product. We added a whole new content type — Documentation — to help you find even more solutions to your programming questions. And we added Developer Story to help developers ditch the outdated resume format. (...) A pattern surfaced when talking to users: even with the addition of Jobs and Documentation to the navigation, many developers weren’t aware of the change."](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/). I don't see any rationale for user experience anywhere:P

Answer (score -8):

This kind of stickiness is almost useless. What kind of information does it provide?

- stackoverflow: a title
- Questions: a headline, the only item with some usefulness
- Tags: a headline for browsing
- Users: a headline for browsing
- Search: only useful if you want to search
- badges: only useful for narcissists
- notifications: only useful the first time you load the page
- sites menu: only useful if you are bored

**Which of the above information is that important, that it is necessary to see it all the time while you read questions, answers or comments?**

This kind of misguided gui design makes it necessary to buy each year a bigger monitor. What comes next? 72pt fonts for headlines?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just disable it if you don't like it now that it's an option.

Comment: Did you read the blog post? Maybe you should read the blog post.

Comment: @BSMP because the default is a useless and stupid idea.

Comment: It's useless and stupid? Where's your evidence? What tests did you run to determine this? Did you read the blog post? It has lots of evidence to support the change, and they did run tests to determine that. Maybe you should read the blog post.

Comment: So you're not changing the setting from the default, which you don't like, *because* you don't like it? That makes no sense.

Comment: @TinyGiant I marked it bold for you.

Comment: I can do that too. **Did you read the blog? Maybe you should read the blog.**