# How do I disable the new nav or at least stick it to top?

Tags: discussion, top-bar

I just refreshed Stack Overflow, and it's all broken. About 8% of my viewport is occupied by a totally useless white panel that moves even when I scroll down haunting me as I browse the site.

It's extremely annoying and actively harms my ability to use this site because of its size and distracting nature. I don't see how this nav is better anyway. It's missing important links such as the link to meta or help center. It's less content for more space on the screen.

Now I don't know why web sites randomly rearrange their UI, but it's the way it is. But is there any option to make it smaller and stay on top? Or ideally to make it look like the old one?

Comment: There is a user preference to make it unsticky - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation

Answer (score -5):

Best I have so far is simple Stylish userstyle to pin it on top:

```
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("meta.stackoverflow.com") {
  header.so-header._fixed {
    position: static !important;
  }
}
```

I also personally find it annoying how Review button creates quite distracting fake notification numbers, so this hides them:

```
  a.-link.js-review-button span.indicator-badge._reviews {
    display: none !important;;
  }
```

It would probably take an userscript to put back the important links that are now missing.

Comment: This post is a good demo that the feature present to hide sticky nav bar is not so well advertised... You don't need a userscript, just click a "no sticky bar" checkbox in your profile.

Comment: You are aware of the [user preference that was added](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)?

Comment: @Stijn No I'm not, unlike the top navigation update, this wasn't featured.