# Shouldn't the top bar be the same on all sites?

Tags: discussion, support, top-bar

I always find myself clicking on the wrong button of the top bar because there is inconsistency on the top bar design among the network sites.

It breaks a known usability law of inertia.

So the question is: Shouldn't the top bar be the same on all sites?

Comment: Since they said that they test the new top bar on StackOverflow + Meta SO, I would say: No, not until they roll it out for all sites.

Comment: Is there a way to choose the old design?

Comment: No. You could play around with Browser Addons which allow you to overwrite the CSS for a site ([I use a small script to reduce the size o the bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344016/what-time-is-it-its-time-for-another-question-about-the-new-navbar-compromis/344966#344966)), but there is no onboard way to get the old bar back.