# "Delete" button in "Recommend Deletion" out of visible range

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I know this is a bit petty, but any chance to budge up the floating window or reducing its size a little so the "Delete" button will be in visible range so we won't have to scroll down every time while reviewing low quality posts? (My laptop resolution is 1336 x 768 which is pretty common on most laptops).

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: [Unsticky your top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your comment. I've tried that but still same problem, the button is still not in visible range. Also, I want the nav bar to be there since I'm reviewing while using other features.