# Headline always visible

Tags: feature-request, design, title

I tend to have a lot of tabs open in my browser at all times. Of these many are from Stack Overflow. The problem I'm having is that when I come back to a tab after say a week, I don't necessarily remember what question that tab answers, and as the page is scrolled down to where I left off I can't see the question. Instead, I have to scroll up to see what the question was, but now I no longer know which answer I was looking at.

Therefore I'd like it if the headline was always visible when you scroll the page.

I don't know if this is more of a personal problem for me or if others also have these issues.

Comment: Can you not just hover over the tab until it displays a tooltip with the title?

Comment: Yeah, that is true, I haven't thought about that. Still to see the title at first glance would be nicer. There is a difference between having to take an extra action vs just seeing the information immediately though.

Comment: To elaborate; say you have 5 tabs open and you need information from one of them, but you don't remember which one, so you ctrl+tab through them. Having to mouse over each tab would cost you a couple of seconds extra. That adds up over time.

Comment: What adds up even more is all that vertical space that would be taken up by making question titles "sticky". When I am trying to read and digest a question or answer, I want the maximum space available for that post's content. You should be able to tell just by skimming the answer what question it is answering. If you can't, there is something rather wrong with the answer.

Comment: In that case one could argue that the search bar is a lot less essential to show all the time than the question headline, replace the search bar with the headline and only show the search bar when scrolled up I'd say.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha people have mixed feelings about "sticky" things - when the top bar was made sticky it lead to an option to disable it for those that really couldn't stand it - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation

Comment: @JonClements ok, sure I can understand the sentiment and it sounds like a good idea to be able to turn it off, and that could be used for the headline as well!

Comment: This sounds like a really niche issue.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha Would it be good enough to just put the title inside the search bar for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made this absolutely tiny userscript which will put the title of the question as a placeholder in the search bar on the sticky menu.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Headline Always Visible
// @version      0.1
// @author       GrumpyCrouton
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    var title = $('div#question-header > h1 > a.question-hyperlink').text();
    if(title) $('.s-input.js-search-field').attr('placeholder', title);
})();
```

To use it, simply install a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/), then use the "Create a new script" button, paste this in and save it. Now, any time you are on a question on any StackExchange site, the title will become the placeholder for the search bar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, awesome, good with some can do attitude instead of all this negativity :)

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha Well the problem you are describing does sound like an incredibly niche problem, but since the solution is so simple I don't see why people were so negative about it.