# Unstick new navigation bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

Would it be possible to make the stickiness of the new navbar configurable?

I understand that some people like to have the bar fixed on their viewport, but a) I don't, and b) now that the bar is bigger than before, it's taking up yet more space which I would like to be able to scroll away.

Also, I don't like seeing myself constantly. I have a mirror in my house, too, but I haven't mounted it to my head yet.

Comment: Ugh, the new nav bar is going to be *sticky?*

Comment: @Pekka웃 [rumour has it](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5695215#5695215), yes...

Comment: Yeah, I just verified, didn't notice that earlier so that might have been added in the last 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: *(puke emoticon)*

Comment: side note: I think this feature might warrant a new tag during the beta testing? cc @stijn

Comment: @rene Perhaps. The announcement also uses the top-bar tag.

Comment: yeah, *The black bar across the top of every Stack Exchange site* we could update that with *The big white floating thingy at the top of your viewport*

Comment: The only thing worse than giant sticky bars is bars that scroll off when you scroll down and pop back in when you scroll up. Let's not do either!

Comment: iPhone all the things! Just kidding... the sticky bar isn't useful. I made a userscript to toggle the top bar to be sticky and literally never use it. Turns out scrolling is easy.

Comment: +1 for last sentence. But let's be real here, SE hates configuration options, so they probably won't add one here. We may be able to get them to drop the stickiness entirely; whichever party ends up unsatisfied will probably have to resort to userscripts, as has been the status quo.

Comment: Pinned bars are for sites that need to keep you clicking around on the site or they don't make money. Stack Overflow visitors are either a) addicted and never leaving anyways, or b) arrived from a search will certainly do so again because they need answers. This is very disappointing.

Comment: Am I the only one that likes a sticky bar? No issue with making it optional though, but like Nathan suggests, I doubt that will happen.

Comment: I would like the *current* nav bar to be sticky (toggle-able, perhaps), and keep it rather than the new one...

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, they're for ease of navigation

Comment: Leave it un-sticky. That way people who want it sticky can install SOX. Those who don't want it sticky can just leave it.

Comment: @DavidG: Maybe, and I wouldn't mind if it were configurable. (In that case I wouldn't even care what the default is.) But as a mandatorium I'd find it extremely annoying, so unless you're finding a non-sticky bar equally annoying, I'd still like for it to be not sticky.

Comment: Don't make it configurable; just make it unsticky like the old one. Pretty sure most people just want the Q/A part; we don't use the navigation enough to justify not scrolling back up again.

Comment: Oh the irony... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273024/position-fixed-navigation-bar

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for that link! That brings up an interesting perspective I hadn't considered. People asking for the fixed position there were thinking of the question index pages, whereas I was thinking of the detailed question pages. I care far less about the appearance of the index, and I can kind of see why one might find a fixed bar useful there. But I also spend far more time on the detail pages (answering questions!), where the fixed bar is utterly disruptive.

Comment: @Matt Worth noting the very mixed response that request got, with the question sitting pretty close to a net 0 score. This question is nearly unanimously supported.

Comment: @jpmc26 [Unanimous](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar#comment435295_341885)? [Are you sure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar#comment435296_341885)?

Comment: For a slightly more unbiased view, there's a few questions on UX.SE that discuss sticky navs. For example [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40636/is-fixed-persistent-navigation-now-considered-good-ux), [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21829/usability-research-on-sticky-headers) and [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31439/whats-the-reason-behind-fixed-position-navbars)

Comment: @DavidG "Nearly" You may need glasses. Also try expanding the vote count into separate +/-.

Comment: @Pekka웃 sticky as a glue, and judging from the total lack of official response here, they don't care a byte about our opinion. (i.e. sticking it up our...)

Answer (score 43):

When I scroll down, I am looking at the content below the navigation bar. I'm reading a question. I'm reading an answer. I'm reading comments. I'm deciding whether to vote up or vote down. I'm writing my own post or comment. Things I'm *not* doing include thinking, "Gee, I hope I get a notification popped up," or, "Oh, I should go look at some completely unrelated stuff." These are things I would much rather have *out of my way* and out of my focus so that I can think about the content I'm trying to read. A sticky scroll bar would only distract from the actual content and reduce the available space for it.

From an aesthetic perspective, sticky elements have the appearance of *moving* separately from the rest of the page (Actually, they really do move separately from the rest of the page.), and they demand your attention every time you adjust the page. This makes them feel very unnatural and out of place, and it makes them rather gaudy. The only way to make a "sticky" element really work well is to make sure the scrollable area doesn't include it in the first place, but doing that in a full browser creates its own separate mess.

Please do not sticky it.

Comment: Probably worth noting that your browser address bar  and quite possibly the bookmarks bar if you haven't disabled it in Chrome also "move separately from the rest of the page" yet you don't find that distracting?

Comment: @DavidG "The only way to make a 'sticky' element really work well is to make sure the scrollable area doesn't include it in the first place..."

Comment: @DavidG: By that logic, every Tom, Dick and Harry who's adding part of a website gets to slap on their own fixed design elements until you have five separate, nested nav and tool bars -- and *I've seen that* in the wild. Everyone is a special snowflake who deserves that special place in my browser (anyone remember the Yahoo tool bar?) for immediate quick access, but please, I'd like my window snow-free. Let *me* decide what I need to have quick access to, won't you?

Comment: @DavidG: No, because those are not part of the document area, do not change depending on what site I visit, and aren't surrounded by the vertical page scrollbar.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My (poorly made) point was that it's a little bit (only a tiny bit) hyperbolic to worry about that and perhaps there was a great deal of plain old "resistance to change". Anyway, what does it matter now we have an option to disable it?

Comment: @DavidG: You asked a question; I answered it. If you don't feel that you need the answer any more then that's up to you ;) I can confirm that I find sticky bars on websites annoying/distracting overall and in general, including this one, and it's not about resistance to change, and it's different from the browser's built-in chrome.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess I was just surprised to see an answer to a comment made a few weeks ago that really isn't relevant any more :) I was quite surprised at the vitriol directed at the stickiness though. It may be distracting to some, but to the average user it's preferred and quicker to use.

Comment: @DavidG: I realise we haven't seen a broad poll conducted on the issue, but the overwhelming sentiment expressed on meta has been _anything_ but _"to the average user it's preferred and quicker to use"_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The angry tend to be the ones who speak loudest, so I always take that sort of thing with a pinch of salt. I prefer to look at (hopefully) unbiased evidence, but that's a bit tough to find here. For example [this answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/45523/50764) has something resembling actual research (though I'm not going to delve into it to determine motivation or bias that may be present in it)

Comment: @DavidG: The other issue is differences across websites of what the navbar is used for. On SO, it's not actually used for navigating; it provides notifications and a site switcher, and that's about it. So arguments about "ease of use" I'm not sure apply - there is no use here. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed, but there are many reasons that make it more desirable. For the casual visitor having the search box visible is useful (arguments about the effectiveness of SO search aside!) and for the veteran, I'm betting people really like to see their rep always visible and inbox notifications. Honestly, this whole episode really reminded me about the "great Facebook redesign of 2014" where I actually heard people say "it's a complete disaster, now I am unable to communicate with any of my friends, I might as well kill myself". :)

Answer (score 26):

So, yeah.

We've made it configurable.

Here's the announcement:

[We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: Just curious, what caused the change of mind? Shog said it won't happen until "the new design is finalized, tested, and widely used". :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - well, we did go through a bunch of A/B tests and the current opt-in period.

Answer (score -3):

This may be a good idea eventually, but making it optional while it's still being tested and designed just makes both of those tasks harder.

Feel free to propose this again once the new design is finalized, tested, and widely used.

Comment: So you're making changes to make things worse and refuse to consider requests until you've already made it worse? Just keep the current design until SE can make one that doesn't make seasoned meta users want to puke even more than in the status quo.

Comment: Have you tried it yet, @bjb568? Considering it wasn't available to folks >= 500 rep until this morning, I'm pretty skeptical that there's any real feedback from "seasoned meta users" here.

Comment: I'm talking about the idea of a sticky nav bar which has been discussed for years. The concensus has always been a solid stream of puke at the idea.

Comment: You're talking about proposals to float the current (or previous) nav bar, @bjb568. That's not what this is. If you want to provide feedback here, go to your profile and opt in to the alpha test (I think you've already done this...?) - then post based on what you actually *see*, not what you're assuming will happen based on ancient discussions and an old design.

Comment: Ok, sure, I enabled it (took a lot more than 5m). Looks good but the floating still makes me puke. Floating is always bad, there was never anything in the meta decisions over the past years that restricted the pukability to the current/past nav.

Comment: So why does this need to be _declined_ right now, then? Just wait to review the request until you're ready.

Comment: To demonstrate to someone that ignoring feature-requests that cannot be addressed isn't actually the worst possible response, @Josh. Also because discussion on a feature that almost no one discussing it has seen is not very useful.