# What happened to the top bar design on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, top-bar

I just wanted to say that I do not like the new style of Stack Overflow with the changed top bar. It is now fixed and uses up more space than it used to (and is necessary).

Since in the west we read from left to right, having the notification icon on the left is better, since your eyes gravitate towards that region.

I'd prefer a 'back to top' button much more than a static top bar.

PS: It also messes up Stylish Plugin.

Comment: To your point about the plugin - Stack Overflow never made any guarantee that any of their site changes would preserve backwards compatibility with *any* plugin, especially one that changes the look and feel of the site.

Comment: Similar feature request: [*Unstick new navigation bar*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar)

Comment: @Makoto That's why I only mentioned it as a PS. Of course it is not their job and the style's creator will probably update (uless the change will be reverted, as I wish...).

Comment: What is "Stylish Plugin"?

Comment: @peter [Stylish is an open-source browser extension that can apply a user-supplied style sheet to a web page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish)