# Top nav bar sticky preferences

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

I saw the [new nav bar update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update?cb=1) and a [linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar) post to make the new nav bar not sticky. I went and checked the box to unstick the bar on the main SO site, but then noticed **it's still sticky here on Meta**. I checked in my preferences on Meta, and there is **another checkbox** to unstick the nav bar.

Can we make the "unstick the nav bar" *shared* between the main site and Meta? If people don't want it sticky in one place, why would they want it in another?

EDIT:
According to @yellowantphil in the comments (now deleted), [it will happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation/343818#343818) [eventually](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update/343815#comment447978_343780), but I'm going to leave this question up to act as an official feature request.

EDIT RE DUPE: This isn't a duplicate of [We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation). That post is asking to make the top nav bar non-sticky (which was done). This question is to make that preference be reflected between main SO and Meta. I've checked and this still isn't the case. The preference still has to be checked for both sites.