# Stats on the top bar's stickiness

Tags: discussion, top-bar, statistics

When the new top bar was introduced, there was quite a bit of controversy regarding the bar's stickiness. Many users liked the design, while many were [strongly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar) [opposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343132/4660897) to it.

This issue [was resolved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation#comment445772_343483) with the introduction of a new setting:
[We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)

Personally, I've come to really like the bar's stickiness. I love that notifications are always visible, no matter how far down on a page I am, and find it much easier to navigate to other parts of the site, with the options always right there.

Since there was so much opposition in the beginning, however, I'm just a bit curious on how big of a deal the fixed design really was. The only way I can think of measuring this is by looking at how many users chose to disable the stickiness. It also would be interesting to see how many of these users are new and how many are highly active users. Does such data exist?

Comment: It's opt out and not one of the easiest to find options. I'd be surprised if the number of users that have stickiness turned off is higher than ~3,000 users. (I am one that does not like that sticky header and have disabled it)

Comment: @Andy Agreed. That's why the only sort of measurement I can think of is looking at how many users were bothered enough to search for the setting and disable it, and can't think of any way to compare enabled vs disabled.

Comment: You can look at how many established users didn't stop contributing because of the incredible annoyance of a sticky bar, based on the fact that programming questions are still getting good answers.

Comment: @CodyGray - Even if *one* established user stopped contributing because of a sticky bar -- or *any* visual design decision -- that would most certainly not be desirable. I hope that isn't the case.

Comment: My guess is that the numbers will be skewed towards the "has left enabled" due to the fact that there is a significant population who isn't even aware that it's *possible* to unsticky the thing due to the lack of discoverability of the configuration. (eg. thanks for letting me know i could make the stupid thing stop taking up valuable vertical real estate on my screen!)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Like I mentioned in a previous comment, that is why I am asking for just the number of users who turned it off, and not a comparison to the number of users who still have it on. And I would not call it stupid. There are users, myself included, who actually like the sticky bar. Just because something is not to your preference, doesn't make it stupid.

Comment: Just because something is to your preference doesn't make it not stupid. :) But I'm not here to argue about language, just pointing out that if I had known that it could be less obnoxious I would've jumped at the opportunity ages ago. And also as an oblique thank-you for letting me know I could make it stop following me around!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of ~7.6 million registered users, 1,912 users have disabled the sticky setting. 1,199 people have disabled then reenabled the sticky header.

Comment: Is there any way you can tell how many of the 1,912 users are heavily active users vs new users?

Comment: The second number is definitely interesting because that shows that 1,199 people are aware of the setting and consciously chose to keep it enabled.

Comment: Yes, but we'd have to agree on a definition for "heavily active" (and also "new") @TotZam. We could pick an arbitrary definition, but what would that tell us? Your original goal here was to re-examine the initial dissatisfaction with the behavior in light of real-world data on how many people were sufficiently dissatisfied to alter it when given the opportunity; the only meaningful breakdown for that data then would be to separate those would complained about it originally from those who were quiet but also changed it. Given the small numbers, I'd be reluctant to do that.

Comment: @Shog9 I was trying to think of a way to separate users that used the site before the design change, and possibly just wanted the setting because they didn't like the change from what they were used to, from users who only started using the site after the new bar was introduced, and still didn't like the sticky bar. I'm not sure if there is any way to really determine that. Again, I just find this interesting, and am curious about how many people are really against fixed top bars.

Comment: @Shog9 The reason I used the term "heavily active" is because I was also thinking if there is a way to tell if users who spend more time on the site every day, whether they are answering questions or helping moderate site, care about their screen space more than users who use the site less. I guess that would be even harder to determine though, since there is no way of telling how much a users use the site just for viewing information.

Comment: Fact of the matter is, the vast majority of users will never change a preference like this @Tot - even if they absolutely detest the default behavior. Options like this are [a fire exit](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75635/when-is-configurable-options-settings-a-bad-thing-in-the-context-of-admin-super/75648#75648) not an enhancement. That's why I was against making this an option in the first place; if there's a serious problem with the behavior of the default, it's *still* going to be a problem for the vast majority of users. Seeing a majority re-enable it puts that fear to rest.