# Make new top bar smaller

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

The new top bar is great, but I feel it is too tall.

As far as I can tell it is currently 60 px in height, and it could easily do with 10 px less of white space.

Also, it's odd that this old related request was denied [Position fixed navigation bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273024/position-fixed-navigation-bar), but the new top bar is fixed nonetheless.

Comment: Looks a lot like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343181/215552, which was declined...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that I could disable the "fixed" feature. This makes the issue go away. Thanks.

Comment: The height isn't a problem if the bar is unstuck from the top actually (which is a coming option) so there is some hope for you at least.

Comment: @TravisJ a coming option? Isn't it already in place in the settings?

Comment: So it is, I hadn't realized it was already released. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: See: [Is the top bar now officially smaller?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360858/4639281) for more info on the [meta-tag:status-completed]

Answer (score 8):

[Seems like this feature request has been completed.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360857/is-the-top-bar-now-officially-smaller/360858#360858) ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) has been applied to this post, replacing the older [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).)

The top bar is now 50px. To quote the answer from 
[Aaron Shekey ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2804712/aaron-shekey):

> We've normalized to 50px throughout Stack Overflow and its network sites. Prior to these changes SO was at 60px and network sites at 40px. The headers now share the same height.