# Is the top bar now officially smaller?

Tags: support, top-bar

I just noticed that the top bar here and on Stack Overflow has shrunk from a height of 60px to now 50px, which looks much better in my opinion. (Apparently there are also some other relatively minor design changes)

Old:

[image]

New:

[image]

Now I'm wondering, is this an official update already or just part of some A/B testing? [Proposals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343518/make-new-top-bar-smaller) of reducing the height had been officially declined in the past, so I'd recommend updating those if this is a final design change.

Comment: It certainly has gotten smaller. It's now the same size as the top bar on other SE sites.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The top bar has indeed gotten smaller by 10px. We've normalized to 50px throughout Stack Overflow and its network sites. Prior to these changes Stack Overflow was at 60px and network sites at 40px. The headers now share the same height.

These changes are intentional and "final", but could change in future iterations.

Comment: I'm surprised no one made a `final` member joke about this.

Comment: @ItamarG3 Well, the statement "These changes are final but could change" made me chuckle :)

Comment: `finally` you managed to `catch` it and fix. Let's `try` to keep it this way.

Comment: @AlexL That comment was exceptional

Comment: @AlexL I don't think you just should just `throw` around keywords here.

Comment: @RickAstley I disagree. I think `this` comment thread is an `Exception`.

Comment: It's still 40px on Super User. Is there any reason for that?