# The color of the current page in the top bar is orange on Meta

Tags: bug, design, meta, top-bar

Since today on Meta, the kind of page I'm currently on (questions, tags, users) is underlined in orange like on the main site:

[image]

It used to be underlined in gray.

I suppose this might have something to do with that [the top bar's height was changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360857/4284627).

Is this a bug or is it intentional?

Comment: I think it looks very smooth with the orange line. I like it because it matches the META Picture. And I don't think that's a bug.

Comment: I'm in a predicament: your question is very valid, but I downvoted to show support for liking the orange. But perhaps I should've upvoted this and the answer. Meta too confusing for me

Comment: @Tas I upvoted the question because I could reproduce the described behaviour - then upvoted the "let's keep it" answer because I like it :)

Answer (score 27):

Let's keep it that way.

Orange is more distinct than a gray underline, and it's consistent with the [meta] block in the logo:

> [image]

Just as that meta block, it's an "accent" that deserves a colour that stands out a little.

---

(for reference, this is the "old" style):

> [image]